# Button layout discrepancy in IE and mozilla

Tags: button, layout

I have been testing an application that i developed in both mozilla and IE(7 and 8). Everything works except the button-layout in IE.

**In IE :**

[image]

**In Mozilla :**

[image]

So in mozilla, its working as expected, but breaks up in IE.

I am using the following piece of code to render the buttons :

```
<tr style="display:block;">
    <td align="left">
       <input type="submit" name="Continue" value="Continue" class="btn-red" style="height: 2.0em; width: 95px; font-size: 13px; cursor: pointer;" />
    </td>
    <td align="left">
    <a href="#" class="btn-gray" style="height: 1.1em;">Cancel</a>
    </td>
</tr>
```

**EDIT :**

**CSS :**

**Red Button :**

```
input.btn-red {
    background: url("https://www.mySite.com/images/red_btn.gif") repeat-x scroll center bottom #D02727;
    border: 2px solid #CE6268;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    display: block;
    font-weight: bold;
    height: auto;
    margin: 10px 10px 10px 0;
    padding: 4px 30px 0.5em;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    width: auto;
}
```

**Gray Button :**

```
a.btn-gray {
    background: url("https://www.mySite.com/images/gray_btn.gif") repeat-x scroll center bottom #B7BDB5;
    border: 2px solid #B2B8B1;
    color: #000000;
    float: left;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 10px 10px 10px 0;
    padding: 4px 30px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 40px;
}
```

Can any one suggest a way to make it work properly in IE ?

Comment: what's in your css related to `btn-red` and `btn-gray` classes? Preferably, make a jsfiddle so it's easier to test everything.

Comment: @PetrČihula : Okay, i am gonna edit the question with the styles .

Comment: @PetrČihula : I have added the styles.

Comment: @PetrČihula : Here's the jsFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/9QEGU/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, check this one out. http://jsfiddle.net/9QEGU/4/

I kinda cleaned up the code, added a `.btn` class to both your buttons to unify the styling a bit and mostly, I removed the second cell from your table which was unecessary. Basically your table was streching out in IE causing the button holders (td) to be 50% of the width, causing the big gap. Generally speaking, I think you should consider avoding table as a holder for buttons at all but that's not related to this issue. Still, simple div would do the trick!

Anyway, here it is. Should you have more questions, feel free to ask :)

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td align="left">
       <input type="submit" name="Continue" value="Continue" class="btn btn-red" />
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-gray">Cancel</a>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>

.btn {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 13px;
    height: 30px;
    width:100px;
    margin: 10px 10px 10px 0;
    text-align: center;
    float:left;
    display:block;
}

input.btn-red {
    background: url("https://www.mySite.com/images/red_btn.gif") repeat-x scroll center bottom #D02727;
    border: 2px solid #CE6268;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

a.btn-gray {
    background: url("https://www.mySite.com/images/gray_btn.gif") repeat-x scroll center bottom #B7BDB5;
    color: #000000;
    text-decoration: none;
    line-height:30px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks i am gonna check this one out and get back to you .

Comment: This is perfect, the layout is perfect, just the continue button is bigger in size, but that's nothing i can't handle. However things are as they must be. Brilliant. Up voted and accepted .